# Book: girl from family of witches, best friend named Gabriel, time travel

Tags: story-identification, novel, witches

I read a book in middle school about a girl who came from a family of witches and they thought she had no powers. As the story progresses, she finds out she does. She also has a best friend named Gabriel (I think) and his power is to find objects, even if it means going in to the past.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**Once a Witch** by Carolyn MacCullough (2009).](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6393119-once-a-witch)

> Tamsin Greene **comes from a long line of witches**, and on the day she was born, her grandmother proclaimed she would be one of the most Talented among them.
>   But Tamsin's magic never showed up.
>   ...
>   a childhood **friend, Gabriel,** comes back to live with her family and his Talent is finding lost objects.
>   ...
>   In a spellbinding display of storytelling, Carolyn MacCullough interweaves witchcraft, romance, and **time travel** in a fantasy that will exhilarate, enthrall, and thoroughly enchant.